# Не могу из расширенного метода класса наследника получить свойство этого самого наследника

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста адекватное решение. Есть два класса.

Первый:

```
class Unit {
        private string name;
        private int? weight;
        private byte[]? coordinates;
        private static int count = 1;
        public int? Weight {
            get {
                return weight;
            }
            set {
                if (value == null || value <= 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка установки веса (" + value + ")! Должна быть > 0.");
                    weight = 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Установленный вес " + name + " = " + value);
                } else {
                    weight = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public string Name {
            get { return name; }
            private set {
                if (value == null || value.Length == 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка установки имени (null)!");
                    name = "Default" + count;
                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Установлено имя " + name);
                } else {
                    name = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public byte[] Coordinates {
            get { return coordinates;  }
            set { coordinates = value; }
        }
        public Unit(string name, int weight, byte[] coordinates) {
            Name = name;
            Weight = weight;
            Coordinates = coordinates;
            printInfo();
        }
        public virtual void printInfo() {
            Console.WriteLine("\nMy name is " + Name + ".\nMy weight is " + Weight + ".\nMy coordinates is:");
            Console.WriteLine("x : " + Coordinates[0] + "\ny : " + Coordinates[1] + "\nz : " + Coordinates[2]);
        }
    }
```

Второй, наследник:

```
    class Player : Unit {
        protected int health;
        public int Health {
            get { return health; }
            set { health = value; }
        }
        public Player(string name, int weight, byte[] coordinates, int health) : base(name, weight, coordinates) {
            Health = health;
        }
        public override void printInfo() {
            base.printInfo();
            Console.WriteLine("My health is " + this.health + "\n");
        }
    }
```

**Проблема** состоит в том, что когда я в основном коде создаю объекты вот так:

```
new Player("222", 2, new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 100);
new Unit("111", 4, new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 });
```

Мой расширенный метод PrintInfo в классе Player после отработки родительского, а затем и своего собственного конструктора **не записывает 100 в health, а почему-то записывает 0.**
Прошу прощения если мой вопрос банальный, не так давно взялся за C#

Comment: потому что, конструкторы вызываются в порядке наследования, сначала базовых классов, а потом наследников, это означает что вызывает, конструктор Unit, потом print (и выводит health = 0), а только потом Player.

Comment: спасибо! а как же мне стоит поступить если в любом случае нужно после установки начальных значений распечатать их?

Comment: я вышел из ситуации, сделав printInfo() разные в этих двух классах, но является ли это хорошей практикой? нет ли более изящного решения с тем, чтобы всё же это был virtual-override метод?